# spl_autoload_register loads class twice

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I keep trying to know what the problem is with this very simple class loader script. 
The class loader looks like this:

```
#src/vendors/Autoloading/lib/ClassLoader.php

namespace App\Vendors\Autoloading;

class ClassLoader
{
    private $path; 

    function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path         = $path; 
    }

    public function load($class)
    {
      if(file_exists(  $class = str_replace(array('\\', '_'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $this->path) . '.php')){
            require $class;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        return spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}
```

The initial class loader had more methods and some functions to validate the file names ... 
but, in the process of debugging I had to narrow it to that.

So, that class loader is being required inside an `autoload.php` file, as you can see below.

```
#src/vendors/autoload.php

namespace App\Vendors;

require 'Autoloading/lib/ClassLoader.php';
$autoload = new Autoloading\ClassLoader('path/Foo/FooClass');
$autoload->register();
```

The `FooClass.php` is located in `src/Foo/FooClass.php`

```
namespace App\Foo;
class FooClass{}
```

and there is actually no problem with the autoloading part, the class gets loaded just fine, but it is done **twice** which shows me the below error. I am calling it from an `index.php` file

```
<?php 

use \App\Foo\FooClass;
FooClass::somefunction();
```

Just using that generates this error.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class path\foo\FooClass in /path/to/index.php on line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your autoloading function is wrong:

```
public function load($class)
{
    if (
        file_exists(  
            $class = str_replace(
                array('\\', '_'), 
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 
                $this->path)
            . '.php')
    ) {
        require $class;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function is calles with the name of the class to be loaded (if impossible, the function should do nothing).

What you do is ignoring the class name, and create a new one based on the path the autoloader is created with. This will always load the same file, with the same class, even if there are different classes to be loaded.

And this explains why you get the error, because no matter which class name gets passed, you always include the one file that is related to the path.

You probably want to use a proper PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoloader. I would recommend using the one that comes with Composer, as you are likely to be using Composer sooner or later yourself. Why not starting today?

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the same error. I must be doing something wrong. Can you show me how you would at-least instantiate the classLoader?

Comment: What have you changed? "Still" implies that you changed something, and it "still" does not work. You are supposed to USE the $class variable, add the path, convert the class name to another path, add ".php" at the end, and require that file if it exists. Don't change $class, create a new $filename.

Comment: I have done those trust me. I am not trolling you, I just spent hours trying to figure this out. I get that `can not redeclare class` file

Comment: Is your current code the one I can see in your question? Then it is still wrong in the way I described in the answer. Note that I did not fix your code in my answer, I only quoted and reformatted it.

Comment: One thing I notice is that your class is named `\App\Foo\FooClass`, but the error message complains about `path\foo\FooClass` being redeclared. Why is this?

Comment: No that is just my error. It says App\Foo\FooClass not path\.. Are there any instances that the `spl_autoload_register` can [load a class twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959855/spl-autoload-register-loads-class-twice/24960198#)? Because that may be the problem here

Comment: Fixed. It seems `require $class;` was actually trying to require the file name + the class with its namespacing. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

Try using `require_once` instead of `require`. Your autoloader won't keep track of what files have been loaded so far.

Here's how I set mine up. I don't use a class. Maybe this will help

```
function PlatformAutoloader($classname) {
    try {
        // Change \ to / so namespacing will work
        $classname = strtolower(str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname));

        if(!@include_once(DIR_CLASSES . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classname . '.php')) return false;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('PlatformAutoloader');
```

Comment: The autoloader is not supposed to be triggered twice for the same class.

Comment: Nope. That hasn't changed a thing

Comment: What kind of exception are you expecting to catch? Is there any PHP-internal function being called that throws exceptions?

Comment: @Sven No. Actually, as stated in the question. I have isolated this class loader in-order to debug it. So, you can say, I only have the classloader, the class and index file to instanciate the class.

Comment: I think that's a relic from when we used to throw an error. You can safely omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the class already exists using [class_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) before checking for the file

Comment: If the class already exists, the autoloader shouldn't be triggered twice, should it?

Comment: @Mark Baker. That is the very first thing I have done. I am 100% it is the autoloading that is loading it twice